# Migration from GaussianProcessor to GaussianProcessRegressor

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I am attempting to migrate some old python code using the scikit-Learn library.

When doing so I encountered the [GaussianProcess](https://scikit-learn.org/0.17/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcess) class which is now fully reimplemented as [GaussianProcessRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor).

I was able to get a running script by replacing

```
self.f = GaussianProcess(corr='linear',theta0=1e-2,thetaL=1e-4,thetaU=1e-1)
```

with

```
self.f = GaussianProcessRegressor()
```

except now I have completely different results when calling predict()...

Any idea how to translate the autocorrelation method (corr) and different theta values with the new API?

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221972/modifying-old-gaussianprocessor-example-to-run-with-gaussianprocessregressor/64226111) talking about pretty much the same problem, but aparently the author was fine about not having the old parameters taken into account, and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535569/scikit-learn-gaussianprocessregressor-vs-gaussianprocess-why-was-gaussianproces) which states the problem precisely as well but does not provide a clear answer.